# Convert bootable USB stick to ISO file

Tags: boot, usb, iso

I am trying to get an ISO file from a bootable USB memory stick. The device name for the stick is `dev/sdf1`. In this answer: [Convert bootable USB to ISO file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240803/convert-bootable-usb-to-iso-file/240810#240810) , `dd` was suggested for copying. So I did:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdf1 of=win7.iso
```

However, the stick has a size of 30G, but only 12G are used. Running the command above, it creates an iso image larger than 12G, I stopped `dd` when the file was > 20G, since I ran out of disk space. 
Is it normal that the ISO file gets so big or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Convert bootable USB to ISO file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240803/convert-bootable-usb-to-iso-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dd` is a 1:1 copy, it copies the entire device regardless what's on it. If you only copy a partition (`sdf1`) it's unlikely to be bootable as the bootloader usually resides on sdf MBR.

If the free space is zeroed, you could save the free space by use of gzip.

To zero the free space, you may use:

```
mount /dev/sdf1 /mnt/tmp
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M | split -b 1G - /mnt/tmp/zerofile
sync
rm /mnt/tmp/zerofile*
umount /mnt/tmp
```

To create a gzip compressed image:

```
dd if=/dev/sdf bs=1M | gzip > win7.img.gz
```

To restore from that image, it's:

```
gunzip < win7.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sdf bs=1M
```

Other alternatives are `partimage` or `ntfsclone` (in case of ntfs), which only store files, not free space, however the result may not be bootable as it's not a 1:1 copy.

Comment: Thanks, but running the command `dd if=/dev/sdf1 bs=1M | gzip > win7.img.gz` still makes win7.img.gz larger than 12G, right now it is already >16G and it is still running, so I have to kill dd due to low disk space.

Comment: Added an instruction to zero free space beforehand. Using split in case of Windows FAT filesystem with max file size limit. Use `of=zerofile` instead if there's no such limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can compress the image like this

```
dd if=/dev/sdf1 conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > usb.img.gz
```

That way, it will not copy the blank parts of the usb stick.

Also `dd` creates a disk image, not an iso.