# Creating an ISO from a bootable pendrive (only the used space)

Tags: usb, live-usb, iso

I have a 128GB bootable pendrive with Windows **Live** on it.
I wanted to create an ISO image of this pen-drive so that I can create a bootable pendrive later.

This question might seem to be [Duplicate] of [Convert bootable USB to ISO file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240803/convert-bootable-usb-to-iso-file),
**but** from the solutions given (`dd` and `gnome-disks`), it creates a **128GB ISO** file,
even though the used space is only 4GB.

Is there any way to create an **ISO of only used space (4GB)**
and later make a bootable pen-drive from it?
I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: What filesystem is your pen, if not ext* you can try to add `-bs=1m -count=5120` to `dd` command and it will create a 5GB ISO from the `beginning` of the drive.

Comment: @IvanTemchenko Thanks :-) It works. When I did `count=800` (some other image of 773MB) It created 839MB file... which is fine BTW :-) But I am still searching for commands or tools (like `imgburn` for windows) which automatically detects Usedspace and creates the image. And also, If I create an image in this way (`dd`) and give it to my friend (uses only windows), he cant use it right?

Comment: about the utility for windows - UltraISO can be  the way 4 u. About the friend - if you can burn created iso, why can't he do the same? )